# How to extract data frame from dictionary containing data frame of different sizes?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, extract

I am using a dictionary to pull data and using a for loop to store iterate through each item and storing it as a unique key:

```
df_dict = {}

key_name = {"item1": "url",
            "item2": "url",
            "item3": "url"
           }
   
for key,value in key_name.items():
    temp_df = spy.search(str(value), quiet=True)
    df_dict["{0}".format(key)] = spy.pull(temp_df, start=start_date, end=end_date, header='Name', grid=None)
```

The spy.search and spy.pull are functions related to Seeq Data Labs but I don't believe to be related to the problem.

This creates a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'item1': [9226 rows x 19 columns],
 'item2': [5 rows x 8 columns],
 'item3': [8300 rows x 33 columns]}
```

I want to store each key as the name of a new data frame named 'item1' that has all of the values stored as a data frame

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: are you looking to do `my_dictionary["item1"] = pandas.DataFrame(my_dictionary["item1"])`?

Comment: are you looking to create a dynamically named variable, something akin to `item1 = my_dictionary["item1"]`?

Comment: @JonSG it would be item1 = my_dictionary['item1'] and my_dictionary['item1] would be a data frame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @JonSG this is going to sounds really dumb but I didn't realize it was in a dataframe already. Thank you for taking time to comment!